# Dropbox Extensions - Is it possible to create/publish a Dropbox Extension?

Tags: dropbox

I'm currently assigned to create a [Dropbox Extension](https://www.dropbox.com/features/extensions).

This is a new feature that Dropbox released last November 2018, here's their [article](https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2018/11/extensions-available-integrations/).

I read the Dropbox API [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). I created a Business trial account (Advance). However, there was nothing about the submission/publishing of extensions.

I also stumbled upon the [Dropbox Partners Portal](https://dropboxpartners.com/) and successfully registered a Tech Partner Account for the company I'm working in. Unfortunately, I also did not found anything about the extensions.

I think this portal is not maintained anymore because:

- General, Marketing, and Technical resources are not available. (even the Welcoming Resources also does not exist)
- The copyright year in the footer also displays 2017.
- There is no KYC, or some kind of evaluation process to verify if the information given is authentic.

*I could be wrong though (For those who actually know, please link an article or announcement).*

So is this new feature only for companies chosen by Dropbox?

Will this ever be open to the public submissions/publishing?

Or maybe this is already open to the public and I'm just looking in the wrong places?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/General-Discussion/Dropbox-Extensions-Is-it-possible-to-create-publish-a-Dropbox/m-p/323180 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the **Dropbox Community forum**:

https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/General-Discussion/Dropbox-Extensions-Is-it-possible-to-create-publish-a-Dropbox/m-p/323180#M25931